# Combine rows if value is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, group-by

I'm using *SQL-Server 2008*. I need to combine rows with the same `Name` and increase counter when:

1. 1 or more `Id's` for the same `Name` is `blank`
2. NOT merge rows if `Id` is `NULL`!
3. NOT merge rows if have the same `Name`, but different `Ids`

**Output for now:**

```
Name    Id   Cnt
John    1     1
Peter   2     2 -- This Peter with the same Id have 2 entries so Cnt = 2
Peter   3     1 -- This is other Peter with 1 entry so Cnt = 1
Lisa    4     1
Lisa   NULL   1
David   5     1
David         1 -- here Id is blank ''
Ralph         2 -- Ralph have both rows with blank Id so Cnt = 2
```

**Desired output:**

```
Name    Id   Cnt
John    1     1
Peter   2     2
Peter   3     1
Lisa    4     1
Lisa   NULL   1 -- null still here
David   5     2 -- merged with blank '' so Cnt = 2
Ralph         2 -- merged both blanks '' so Cnt = 2
```

**SQL-Query:**

This is sample query what I'm using for now:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Id, 
       COUNT(Id) AS Cnt
FROM Employees                       
WHERE Condition = 1                 
GROUP BY Name, Id
```

**What I have tried:**

Added aggregate `MAX` to `Id` in `SELECT` clause and grouped by `Name` only, but in this case merged rows with `NULL` values and with the same names with different `Id's` what is wrong for me.

```
SELECT Name, 
       MAX(Id), -- added aggregate
       COUNT(Id) AS Cnt
FROM Employees                       
WHERE Condition = 1                 
GROUP BY Name -- grouped by Name only
```

Have you any ideas? If anything is not clear about problem - ask me, I will provide more details.

**UPDATE:**

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
  Name NVARCHAR(40),
  Id NVARCHAR(40)
);
```

**DML**

```
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES
 ('John' ,   '1')
,('Peter',   '2')
,('Peter',   '2')
,('Peter',   '3')
,('Lisa' ,   '4')
,('Lisa' ,  NULL)
,('David',   '5')
,('David',   '')
,('Ralph',   '')
,('Ralph',   '')
```

**DEMO:**  <kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33587/1)</kbd>

Comment: +1 for a well-formed question. however, it's better to include the relevant tables ddl+dml for the sample data so that anyone that wants to answer will be able to easily reproduce it.

Comment: Strange design of data in your table... Would you consider change data?

Comment: @Anton there is very simplified data, there is no way to change It.

Comment: How do you merge when Peter, 2, 2; Peter, 3, 1; Peter, (blank), 1

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas For example: update Employees table and set Id not blank for names where it is blank. Your task will be much more easier in this case.

Comment: @Eric in this case result should be: Peter, 2, 3; Peter, 3, 2;, increase counter for both and should gone row with blank value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

```
DECLARE @Data table (Name varchar(10), Id varchar(10)) -- Id must be varchar for blank value
INSERT @Data VALUES
('John', '1'),
('Peter', '2'),('Peter', '2'), 
('Peter', '3'),--('Peter', ''), --For test
('Lisa', '4'),
('Lisa', NULL),
('David', '5'),
('David', ''),
('Ralph', ''), ('Ralph', '')
```

---

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    Id, 
    COUNT(*) + ISNULL(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @data WHERE Name = d.Name AND Id = '' AND d.Id <> '')
    , 0) AS Cnt 
FROM @data d 
WHERE 
    Id IS NULL 
    OR Id <> '' 
    OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @data WHERE Name = d.Name AND Id <> '')
GROUP BY Name, Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` statement inside your `SELECT`. It allows you to set Id = [some value] for employees where it is blank. Query can be something like this:

```
SELECT E.Name, 
             CASE 
                  WHEN E.Id = ''
                     THEN 
                        (Select Employees.Id from Employees where Employees.Id <> '' and E.Name = Employees.Name)
                  ELSE E.Id 
             END as Idx, 
       COUNT(Id) AS Cnt
FROM Employees as E                     
WHERE Condition = 1                 
GROUP BY Name, Idx
```

Answer (score 1):

A version with window functions:

```
SELECT Name,ID, Cnt from
( select *, sum(1-AmtBlank) over (partition by Name, ID) + sum(case id when 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Name) Cnt,
       rank()  over (partition by Name order by AmtBlank  ) rnk,
       row_number() over (partition by Name, ID order by AmtBlank) rnr
    FROM (select * , case id when '' then 1 else 0 end AmtBlank from Employees /*WHERE Condition = 1*/ ) e
) c where  rnr=1 and rnk = 1
```

This uses `case id when '' then 1 else 0 end AmtBlank` to keep an amount for the blank amounts per row (making the amount for non blanks 1-AmtBlank) and 2 window functions, one with id for a count per name and id (`sum(1-AmtBlank) over (partition by Name, ID)`) and a count for all blanks in a name section (`sum(case id when 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Name)`)
The `row_number` is used to subsequently fetch only the first rows of a group and `rank` is used to only include the blank records when there are no records with an id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. using cte and joins

```
;with cte as (
SELECT Name, 
       Id, 
       COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM Employees                       
WHERE isnull(Id,1)<>''               
GROUP BY Name, Id
),

cte2 as (SELECT Name,id, COUNT(*) AS Cnt    FROM Employees WHERE Id='' GROUP BY Name,id)

select cte.Name,cte.Id,(cte.cnt + ISNULL(cte2.Cnt,0)) as cnt
from cte 
left JOIN  cte2
on cte.Name = cte2.Name 
union all 
select cte2.Name,cte2.Id,cte2.cnt
from cte2 
left JOIN  cte
on cte.Name = cte2.Name 
where cte.Name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple syntax is compatible with older versions or other RDBMSs
-- Self explained on comments
**edited:**

```
select name, id, count(*) from (
    -- adds "normal" records
    select name, id from Employees where id is null or id <> ''
    -- adds one record to each name-notBlankId for each blank id  (David, Peter if you add 'Peter','')
    -- uncomment /*or id is null*/ if you want even null ids to recieve merged blanks
    union all
    select e1.name, e1.id
    from (select distinct name, id from Employees where id <> '' /*or id is null*/ ) as e1 
    inner join (select name, id from Employees where id = '') as e2 on e1.name = e2.name
    -- adds records that can't be merged (Ralph)
    union all
    select name, id from Employees e1
    where e1.id = ''
      and not exists(select * from Employees e2 where e1.name = e2.name and e2.id <> '')
) as fullrecords
group by name, id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
;WITH NonBlanks AS
(
  SELECT Name, 
         Id, 
         COUNT(ISNULL(Id, 1)) AS Cnt
  FROM Employees
  WHERE ISNULL(Id,0) <> ''
  GROUP BY Name, Id
 )
,Blanks AS
(
  SELECT Name, 
         Id, 
         COUNT(ISNULL(Id, 1)) AS Cnt
  FROM Employees
  WHERE ID = ''
  GROUP BY Name, Id
)
SELECT CASE WHEN nb.NAME IS NULL THEN b.NAME ELSE nb.NAME END NAME,
       CASE WHEN nb.NAME IS NULL THEN b.Id ELSE nb.Id END Id,
       (ISNULL(nb.Cnt,0) + ISNULL(b.Cnt,0)) Cnt
FROM NonBlanks nb FULL JOIN  Blanks b 
     ON nb.Name = b.Name
```